# Assign ValidatesOnDataErrors in a Style

Tags: wpf, validation, styles

I have a wpf form that has many controls. I'm doing all sort of validations on the user input and the source as well. I need to Set ValidatesOnDataErrors in Style.
It is not recognizing the property ValidatesOnDataErrors.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
  <Setter Property="ValidatesOnDataErrors" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a property on the `Binding` class, you can't set it in a style (because bindings cannot be styled).

Comment: ahhh, but can you EXTEND the binding class to have it default to true?

Comment: @DRapp: Possibly, why not just try it?